# Why populate returns empty results in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to populate my property (subCategories) but it's return empty although there are results in my database. Did I have miss something? I followed the populate method in mongoose:

```
const Document = mongoose.model('Document', new mongoose.Schema({
      name: { type: String },
      description: { type: String },
      subCategory: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId }
}));

const Category = mongoose.model('Category', new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String },
    subCategories: [
      {
        name: { type: String }
      }
    ]
  })
);

var cat1 = await new Category({ name: 'cat1', subCategories: [{ name: 'sub-1-cat-1' }, { name: 'sub-1-cat-2' } ]}).save();
var cat2 = await new Category({ name: 'cat2', subCategories: [{ name: 'sub-2-cat-1' }, { name: 'sub-2-cat-2' } ]}).save();

await new Document({ name: 'doc1', description: 'blabla', subCategory: cat2.subCategories[1] }).save();

const results = Document.find({}).populate('subCategory');

// results[0].subCategory is empty?! why?
```

Comment: The subcategory must be a mongoose model in order to be populated, currently the subCategory that you're trying to populate is just an array item for Category model

Comment: can be done anyway? not using populate maybe? or using populate with another syntax?

Answer (score 0):

The subcategory must be a mongoose model in order to be populated, currently the subCategory that you're trying to populate is just an array item for Category model so I would refactor the code you've posted above to this:

```
const SubCategory = mongoose.model('SubCategory', new mongoose.Schema({
      name: { type: String }
}));

const Document = mongoose.model('Document', new mongoose.Schema({
      name: { type: String },
      description: { type: String },
      subCategory: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "SubCategory" }
}));

const Category = mongoose.model('Category', new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String },
    subCategories: [
      { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "SubCategory" }
    ]
  })
);

var sub1Cat1 = await new SubCategory({ name: 'sub-1-cat-1' }).save();
var sub1Cat2 = await new SubCategory({ name: 'sub-1-cat-2' }).save();

var sub2Cat1 = await new SubCategory({ name: 'sub-2-cat-1' }).save();
var sub2Cat2 = await new SubCategory({ name: 'sub-2-cat-2' }).save();

var cat1 = await new Category({ name: 'cat1', subCategories: [sub1Cat1, sub1Cat2 ] }).save();
var cat2 = await new Category({ name: 'cat2', subCategories: [sub2Cat1, sub2Cat2 ] }).save();

await new Document({ name: 'doc1', description: 'blabla', subCategory: cat2.subCategories[1] }).save();

const results = Document.find({}).populate('subCategory');

// results[0].subCategory is not empty!
```

Comment: I do want Category and SubCategory in the same collection. why it's can't be done?

Comment: @JonSud You can either have it the way I mentioned above or instead of trying to populate the Document model with a subCategory just have the object in there. You can't do it the way you just did it above because mongoose populates fields using the ObjectId that is specified in that field and the `ref` property as well (the ref property is required so mongoose knows which collection to fetch for documents with the specified ObjectIds)